# Returning the memory used so I can predict the memory required to compute ML algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, memory, memory-management, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am running a Random Forest ML script using a test size data set 5 k observations with a set number of parameters with a varying number of forests. My real model is closer to 1 million observations with 500+ parameters.  I am trying to calculate how much memory this model would  require assuming x number of forests.

In order to do this I could use a method of returning how much memory was used in a running of the script. Is it possible to return this, so that I can calculate the RAM required to compute the full model?

I currently use the following to tell me how long it takes to compute:

```
global starttime
print "The whole routine took %.3f seconds" % (time() - starttime)
```

#### Edit Re to my own answer

Feel like I am conversing with myself a little but hey ho, I tried running the following code to find out how much memory is actually being used, and why when I increase the number of `n_estimators_value` my PC runs out of memory. Unfortunately all of the % memory usage come back the same, I assume this is because it is calculating the memory usage at the incorrect time, it needs to record it at its peak whilst actually fitting the random forest. See code:

```
psutilpercent = psutil.virtual_memory()
print "\n", " --> Memory Check 1 Percent:", str(psutilpercent.percent) + "%\n"

n_estimators_value = 500
rf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = n_estimators_value, oob_score=True, random_state = 1)

psutilpercent = psutil.virtual_memory()
print "\n", " --> Memory Check 1 Percent:", str(psutilpercent.percent) + "%\n"
```

Any methods to find out the peak memory usage? I am trying to calculate how much memory would be required to fit a rather large RF, and I cant calculate this without knowing how much memory my smaller models require.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/time` reports peak memory usage for a program. There's also the [`memory_profiler`](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler) for Python.